# Cannot Write Math properly when using the fouriernc package

Tags: math-mode, fonts, fourier

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}
    $A = 4a$
\end{document}
```

This produces the following log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.8) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.10.27)  29 OCT 2021 22:50
entering extended mode
**./nwedfasdf.tex
(nwedfasdf.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count182
\c@section=\count183
\c@subsection=\count184
\c@subsubsection=\count185
\c@paragraph=\count186
\c@subparagraph=\count187
\c@figure=\count188
\c@table=\count189
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fouriernc\fouriernc.sty
Package: fouriernc 2005/12/20 1.0 fouriernc package

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fourier\fourier.sty
Package: fourier 2020/03/03 2.2 fourier-GUTenberg package

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
Now handling font encoding FML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding FML
Now handling font encoding FMS ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding FMS
Now handling font encoding FMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding FMX

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+futs on input line 1
12.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fourier\t1futs.fd
File: t1futs.fd 2004/03/02 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for T1/futs.
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fourier\fourier-orns.sty
Package: fourier-orns 2020/03/03 2.2 fourier-ornaments package
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 63.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `T1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 63.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> T1/futs/m/n on input line 63.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `T1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 63.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/futs/m/n on input line 63.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/futs/m/n --> T1/futs/b/n on input line 64.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `letters' on input line 72.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OML' has changed to `FML' for symbol font
(Font)              `letters' in the math version `normal' on input line 72.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> FML/futmi/m/it on input line 72.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OML' has changed to `FML' for symbol font
(Font)              `letters' in the math version `bold' on input line 72.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> FML/futmi/m/it on input line 72.
\symotherletters=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  FML/futmi/m/it --> FML/futmi/b/it on input line 74.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `otherletters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  FML/futm/m/it --> FML/futm/b/it on input line 75.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 76.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 77.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 78.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 79.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 80.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 81.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 82.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 83.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 84.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 85.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 86.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `symbols' on input line 126.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `FMS' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 126.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> FMS/futm/m/n on input line 126.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `FMS' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 126.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> FMS/futm/m/n on input line 126.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 127.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `FMX' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 1
27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> FMX/futm/m/n on input line 127.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `FMX' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 127
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> FMX/futm/m/n on input line 127.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 128.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/futs/bx/n on input line 128.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/futs/bx/n on input line 128.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathrm on input line 129.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> T1/futs/m/it on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> T1/futs/m/it on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathcal on input line 131.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \parallel on input line 147.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 161.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varkappa on input line 199.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varvarrho on input line 200.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \Vert on input line 223.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \vert on input line 228.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \Downarrow on input line 238.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \backslash on input line 240.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rangle on input line 242.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \langle on input line 244.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rbrace on input line 246.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lbrace on input line 248.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rceil on input line 250.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lceil on input line 252.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rfloor on input line 254.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lfloor on input line 256.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 260.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 261.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 262.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 263.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 264.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 265.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 266.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 267.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 268.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 269.
\symUfutm=\mathgroup5
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `letters' on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  FML/futmi/m/it --> FML/fncmi/m/it on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  FML/futmi/b/it --> FML/fncmi/m/it on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `otherletters' on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `otherletters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  FML/futm/m/it --> FML/fncm/m/it on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `otherletters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  FML/futm/b/it --> FML/fncm/m/it on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  FML/fncmi/m/it --> FML/fncmi/b/it on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `otherletters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  FML/fncm/m/it --> FML/fncm/b/it on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  T1/futs/m/n --> T1/fnc/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/futs/b/n --> T1/fnc/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/fnc/m/n --> T1/fnc/b/n on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `symbols' on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  FMS/futm/m/n --> FMS/fncm/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  FMS/futm/m/n --> FMS/fncm/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  T1/futs/bx/n --> T1/fnc/b/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/futs/bx/n --> T1/fnc/b/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathrm on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font)                  T1/futs/m/n --> T1/fnc/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/futs/m/n --> T1/fnc/m/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  T1/futs/m/it --> T1/fnc/m/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/futs/m/it --> T1/fnc/m/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathcal on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathcal' in version `normal'
(Font)                  FMS/futm/m/n --> FMS/fncm/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathcal' in version `bold'
(Font)                  FMS/futm/m/n --> FMS/fncm/m/n on input line 38.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+fnc on input line 3.


(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fouriernc\t1fnc.fd
File: t1fnc.fd 2005/12/13 scaled font definitions for T1/fnc.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/fnc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.18341pt on input line 3.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-08-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count190
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
)
(nwedfasdf.aux)
\openout1 = `nwedfasdf.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for FML/fncmi/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for FML+fncmi on input line
 3.
 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fouriernc\fmlfncmi.fd
File: fmlfncmi.fd 2005/12/20 Fontinst v1.928 font definitions for FML/fncmi.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for FMS/fncm/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for FMS+fncm on input line 
3.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fouriernc\fmsfncm.fd
File: fmsfncm.fd 2005/12/20 Fontinst v1.928 font definitions for FMS/fncm.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for FMX/futm/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for FMX+futm on input line 
3.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fourier\fmxfutm.fd
File: fmxfutm.fd futm-extension
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/fnc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.71893pt on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/fnc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.57996pt on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `FMX/futm/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.07397pt on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `FMX/futm/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.63599pt on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `FMX/futm/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.51999pt on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for FML+fncm on input line 
4.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fouriernc\fmlfncm.fd
File: fmlfncm.fd 2005/12/20 Fontinst v1.928 font definitions for FML/fncm.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/futm/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.07397pt on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/futm/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.63599pt on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/futm/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.51999pt on input line 4.
 [1

{C:/Users/Krish/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (nwedfasdf.aux)
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1159 strings out of 478927
 16000 string characters out of 2862391
 299555 words of memory out of 3000000
 19043 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 421432 words of font info for 55 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 67i,5n,73p,204b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file fourier-ms): Font fourier-ms at 604 not found

 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I am new to LaTeX. Am i missing the installation to the fourier-ms font library? If so, how should I install it? And why didnt it come bundled while using the fouriernc package? Am I missing some arguements to it? I could not find any solution online and have to resort to not using any fonts for the time being.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: go to the miktex console (user mode) and trigger the task to refresh the font map files.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer how am I supposed to do that exactly? Please elaborate

Comment: Open the miktex console and look in the menu "tasks".

Comment: Yess, it worked. Thanks!